# Alterar nós ArrayList

Tags: java

Se tenho um `ArrayList<Integer> listInt` por exemplo, suponhamos que nesse `ArrayList` tenham:

```
int a, int b, int c; //a = 2 b=3 c=4
```

e se depois eu trocar o valor de `a`, `b` e `c` por exemplo para `a=1 b=2 c=3`

Por eu ter trabalhado com os mesmos "objetos" armazenados no arraylist, quando eu acesso ele, obtenho os dados novos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, porque `a`, `b` e `c` são do tipo `int`, que é um **tipo primitivo**. Em Java, tudo o que é passado como argumento para uma função (incluindo construtores) é passado **por valor** (i.e. copiado). Mesmo uma referência é passada por valor (i.e. o objeto pode não ser copiado, mas o "ponteiro" para ele é).

```
int a = 10;
foo(a); // "foo" recebe uma cópia de a
```

No caso de um `ArrayList` temos uma complicação adicional: ele só aceita **objetos** como elementos da lista, não tipos primitivos. Nas versões antigas de Java, era inclusive obrigatório você criar explicitamente um `Integer` a partir de seus `int`s antes de passar para `ArrayList`:

```
int a = 10;
meuArrayList.add(new Integer(a));
```

A partir de uma certa versão (não me lembro bem qual) Java implementou a funcionalidade ***autoboxing*** - que permite que você use `int` e `Integer` como se fosse uma coisa só (embora "por baixo dos panos" ele continua criando o objeto para você, de modo que isso afeta a performance e o uso de memória):

```
int a = 10;
meuArrayList.add(a); // Na verdade, está sendo adicionado: new Integer(a)
int b = meuArrayList.get(0); // Na verdade, está sendo retornado:
                             // meuArrayList.get(0).intValue()
```

A única situação em que uma modificação feita fora da lista afeta os objetos dentro da lista é se os objetos adicionados forem **mutáveis**, e você estiver mexendo no **conteúdo** dos mesmos - não na sua referência:

```
int[] a = new int[]{ 10, 20, 30 };
meuArrayList.add(a);

// Mexeu no conteúdo de a
a[1] = 40;
meuArrayList.get(0)[1]; // 40

// Mexeu na referência a
a = new int[]{ 50, 60, 70 };
meuArrayList.get(0)[1]; // 40 (continua sendo o array antigo)
```

No caso do *autoboxing*, entretanto, não haveria problema nem mesmo se `a`, `b` e `c` fossem do tipo `Integer`: já que ele é **imutável**. Como não dá para modificá-lo uma vez criado, nada que você fizer fora do `ArrayList` vai afetar os valores dentro dele.

Answer (score 2):

Quando voce faz:

```
List<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<>();

int a = 2, b = 3, c = 4;

listInt.add(a); //linha 5
listInt.add(b); //linha 6
listInt.add(c); //linha 7
```

Nas linhas 5, 6 e 7 você está criando 3 objetos do tipo `Integer` antes de adicioná-lo ao seu `ArrayList` e está inicializando esses objetos com os valores 2, 3 e 4. Isso é feito automaticamente com um mecanismo chamado de [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), ele cria um objeto sem a necessidade do operador `new` para automaticamente converter um primitivo para um objeto em ocasiões que são reservadas para objetos, como é o caso do [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Supondo que você tivesse feito:

```
List<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<>();

Integer a = 2, b = 3, c = 4;

listInt.add(a);
listInt.add(b);
listInt.add(c);

a *= 2; //linha 9
b *= 2; //linha 10
c *= 2; //lina 11
```

Talvez você pense que agora sim consegue mudar o valor dos objetos `Integers` que estão dentro do `ArrayList`, porém isso não acontece pois nas linhas 9, 10 e 11 você novamente através dos mecanismos de `Autoboxing` e `Autounboxing` está criando novos objetos. Isso acontece pois `Integers` são imutáveis, ou seja, você não pode alterar o valor do objeto, mas você pode criar um novo objeto com um novo valor e fazer com que suas variáveis de referência `a`, `b` e `c` referenciem esse novo objeto.