# Problema com Getters e Setters de um Array

Tags: java, array, get, set

Estou com problemas para acessar arrays em um classe singleton

Classe Info

```
public class Info {
private static Info cinfo;

private String[] first_name;
private String[] last_name;
private String[] nickname;


public static Info getInstance() {
    if (cinfo == null) {
        cinfo = new Info();
    }
    return cinfo;
}

public String getFirst_name(int index) {
    return first_name[index];
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name , int index) {
    this.first_name[index] = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name(int index) {
    return last_name[index];
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name, int index) {
    this.last_name[index] = last_name;
}

public String getNickname(int index) {
    return nickname[index];
}

public void setNickname(String nickname, int index) {
    this.nickname[index] = nickname;
}
```

}

Main

public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Info cinfo = new Info();
    cinfo.setFirst_name("Lucas", 0);
    cinfo.setFirst_name("Bertz", 1);
    System.out.println(cinfo.getFirst_name(0));

}
```

}

Erro

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Info.setFirst_name(Info.java:28)
at main.main(main.java:6)
```

Comment: Por que você está representando seus dados desse jeito? Por que não usar classes? Vou responder a respeito do erro que você está tendo, mas gostaria de saber qual a motivação por trás desse design.

Comment: A propósito, se você está instanciando `Info` com `new`, então sua classe não é singleton... O construtor de `Info` deveria ser privado, e a primeira linha do seu `main` deveria ser `Info cinfo = Info.getInstance();`

Comment: @mgibsonbr Isso é apenas um teste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu erro ocorre porque o array `first_name` não está instanciado (i.e. ele é `null`). Ao tentar acessá-lo, ocorre o `NullPointerException`.

Em Java, arrays têm tamanho fixo, de modo que não é possível criar um array simples que se redimensione para receber novos elementos (para isso, o mais adequado é usar `java.util.ArrayList`). Por isso, você precisa escolher um tamanho padrão para seu(s) array(s), e já no construtor (ou na inicialização da instância) criar um array com esse tamanho:

```
public class Info {
    private static Info cinfo;

    private String[] first_name = new String[10];
    private String[] last_name = new String[10];
    private String[] nickname = new String[10];
```

Dessa forma, você terá um array com 10 elementos, todos `null`. Sua atribuição passará a ser bem-sucedida, desde é claro que o índice esteja dentro do intervalo aceitável (`0` a `9`). Ou seja, é importante verificar isso na chamada da função, e reagir de acordo (lançar uma exceção, substituir o array por outro maior, etc).

Comment: Era isso que eu estava pensando... como funciona o arraylist? nunca usei antes, vc teria um exemplo ai?

Comment: Há várias perguntas aqui mesmo no SOpt sobre `ArrayList`, procure e você achará vários exemplos. [Aqui tem um](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13928/215), incluindo referência para a documentação oficial (esta em inglês). [Aqui tem um outro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4870/215).